# Oracle return the year of the following October

Tags: sql, oracle, date

From within Oracle I want to return the year of the next October.

i.e today (March 5, 2014), next October falls in 2014, but when I run the same piece of SQL in Nov 2014, I want it to return 2015 as the next October falls the following year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select extract (year from add_months(sysdate, 2)) from dual;
```

Tested on http://sqlfiddle.com/:

```
select extract (year from add_months(to_date('31Oct2014', 'ddMONyyyy'), 2)) from dual;
select extract (year from add_months(to_date('1Nov2014', 'ddMONyyyy'), 2)) from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks so much to you both got it working form your code Jens

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate)<10 THEN TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') 
ELSE TO_CHAR((sysdate + interval '1' year), 'YYYY') END AS year FROM DUAL;
```